# C Changing value of array of struct through reference

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-to-array

I asked a similar question before, when I didnt know what was the problem of my code. Just as I was recommended I will give it in a better format.

This is an example of what happens to my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id_prod;
} producto;

void carga_producto(producto **productos)
{
    int n = 1;
    printf("Productos before the calloc: %d\n ", productos);
    *productos = (producto *)calloc(1, sizeof(producto));
    printf("Productos after the calloc: %d\n ", productos);
    while (n < 3)
    {
        printf("Value of n %d\n", n);
        producto *temp = realloc(*productos, (n + 1) * sizeof(producto));
        *productos = temp;
        printf("position of temp: %d\n", temp);
        printf("Productos: %d\n ", productos);
        n++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    producto *productos;
    carga_producto(&productos);
}
```

As you can clearly see, no pointer is being changed neither by the realloc or the = .  both *productos and *temp stay intact.

Since their values dont change I cant add more. Both the calloc and realloc arent doing anything.

I tried playing with the realloc and malloc and checking for ways to fix this but I cant find a way to change the ptrs.

//THIS IS THE RESULT I OBTAINED

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Esizon\test> ./datos.exe
Productos before the calloc: 719321432
Productos after the calloc: 719321432
Value of n 0
position of temp: 1280342752
Productos: 719321432
 Value of n 1
position of temp: 1280342752
Productos: 719321432
```

//I WAS EXPECTING A CHANGE OF VALUES SUCH AS THIS,

where the calloc finds a positions for the pointer and then, when Temp is updated, asigning the value of the ptr temp to the pointer productos.

And on the second cycle I expected it to change the value of temp when it was assigned more memory, but it didnt do anything.

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Esizon\test> ./datos.exe
Productos before the calloc: 719321432
Productos after the calloc: 426416321
Value of n 0
position of temp: 1280342752
Productos: 1280342752
 Value of n 1
position of temp: 512346132
Productos: 512346132
```

---

Applying your changes

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id_prod;
} producto;

void carga_producto(producto **productos)
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("Productos before the calloc: %d\n ", productos);
    *productos = (producto *)calloc(1, sizeof(producto));
    printf("Productos after the calloc: %d\n ", productos);
    while (n < 2)
    {
        printf("Value of n %d\n", n);
        producto *temp = realloc(*productos, (n + 1) * sizeof(producto));
        *productos = temp;
        printf("position of temp: %d\n", *temp);
        printf("Productos: %d\n ", *productos);
        n++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    producto *productos;
    carga_producto(&productos);
}
```

The result is

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Esizon\test> ./datos.exe
Productos before the calloc: -1270876504
 Productos after the calloc: -1270876504
 Value of n 0
position of temp: 0
Productos: -1072923936
 Value of n 1
position of temp: 0
Productos: -1072923936
```

Still no change to productos and temp is not even initialized.

try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 3

typedef struct {
    int id_prod;
} producto;

producto* carga_producto(int max) {
    producto *productos = calloc(1, sizeof(producto));
    if (productos) {
      printf("Producto[0]: id=%d\n", productos->id_prod);
      for (int n = 1; n < max; n++) {
          producto *temp = productos;
          productos = realloc(temp, (n + 1) * sizeof(producto));
          if (productos) productos[n].id_prod = n; else { printf("%s\n", "Something wrong"); free(temp); break; }
          printf("Producto[%d]: id=%d\n", n, productos[n].id_prod);
      }
    }
    return productos;
}

int main() {
    producto *productos = carga_producto(MAX);
    if (!productos) return 1;
    free(productos);
    return 0;
}
```

This works instead of sending the data through ref I just receive a product array. It is not a fix (and I have tried wwhat every other comment said one by one till 5 am) but it will do the work I need. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Please , remember this is a very minimized version of the real program. I was asked to simplify it so the problem was easier to see and solve. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `realloc` can return the same pointer if more memory was available at the tail end of the original allocation. `%p` is the correct printf format for a poineter.

Comment: and your first call to realloc requests the same amount of memory as you allocated in the call to calloc, so no change is needed and no change to the pointer is expected as no more memory is requested.

Comment: Once you fix the format string you're still printing the wrong thing. `productos` will never change, but `*productos` might. https://godbolt.org/z/E9W7f6v3M

Comment: The value of productos in carga_producto() is the address of the different productos variable from main and is never changed in carga_producto(), which is fine.

Comment: Changed it a bit so you can see the problem. Again, you can see that *productos = temp does not change productos. With a = sign I cant assign the value of temp to productos.   And when there are more calls to realloc with bigger sizes the values of temp and productos DONT change. Remember that this is a very simplified version of a problem with a LOT more data. I just simplified it to show how both temp and productos will not change. In the original data those values where huge arrays of complex structures, so the values should change. 
This is the simplified version I was asked for.

Comment: There I assigned the prints so they show where the ptrs are aiming. As you can see temp is nullptr aiming at 0 and will not change. And productos wont change at all.

This kind of denies the theory of temp having enough space to start. It starts aiming at nullptr.

Comment: I'd suggest you take some time examining the code sample @RetiredNinja provided via a link to Compiler Explorer. It really does deal with the issue you are trying to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `productos` in `carga_producto` is the address passed to it by `main`.

`*productos = (producto *)calloc(1, sizeof(producto));` does not assign a value to `productos`. It assigns a value to the thing `productos` points to, `*productos`.

To see the value, print `*productos`, not `productos`.

Use `%p` to print a pointer, not `%d`, and convert the pointer to `void *`, as in:

`printf("Productos before the calloc: %p\n ", (void *) *productos);`

It is an incorrect deduction to conclude that because the address of an allocation did not change, more memory was not reserved. The memory management software may reserve more memory at the same starting address.